# How can I save text to a file in R?

Tags: r, text, save

I have a R function which can generate the LaTeX code (the output is the LaTex code) by using `cat()`, while now I want to save these LaTeX code, but I don't know which function can save these LaTeX code...

Comment: Are you sure Sweave would be of no help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like to use the `sink()` function:

```
latex.code <- function(){
   cat("\\begin{align}\n")
   cat("[X'X]^{-1}X'y\n")
   cat("\\end{align}\n")
}
sink(file='ols.txt')
latex.code()
sink()
```

Edit: Obviously, you can choose the file path where the file will be saved by changing the sink argument such as: `sink(file='c:/Users/Eva/Desktop/ols.txt')`, or `sink(file='~/ols.txt')`

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your R function returns a character string of LaTeX code (your question would be much improved if you made it more concrete, with some specific examples), you can output something like that to a file using the cat() function, and specifying a file using the file= argument. You can read about it via ?cat.

Comment: YES, what my R function return is string by using cat(), but I donnot know how to save this cat()...

Comment: I have tried, while if cat(@@@@, file="argument"), where is my file saved??

Comment: @user471448 here is example of how I use cat on my unix machine.  cat(sum(1,2), "/Users/ditkin/Desktop/foo.txt")

Comment: Follow my advice (and the posting guide) and provide a minimal reproducible example (i.e. code that I can run myself), and I'll try to help some more.

Comment: @Eva All files are saved, provided absolute path is not set, to `setwd()`.

Answer (score 3):

If it happens that you have your output in a character vector (i.e. you are using something like `cat(<something>)` to have it written to the console), you can use `writeLines` function, like this:

```
writeLines(<something>,"filename.txt")
```

However the best way to make a LaTeX file in R is to use either Sweave or make a brew template.